# Short specified distance in space: Abstand or Distanz?

Tags: synonym

Wenn ich richtig verstanden habe, werden "Abstand" und "Distanz" für "a short specified distance" und "Entfernung" für "a large specified distance" verwendet. Wenn der Kontext ein Leichtathletikwettbewerb ist, verwendet man stattdessen "Strecke".

Wie kann man zwischen "Abstand" und "Distanz" wählen? Ich habe gelesen, dass "Distanz" im mathematischen Kontext üblicher ist, aber ich denke, "Abstand" ist auch richtig. Ich gebe zwei Beispiele:

- Der Abstand / die Distanz zwischen den beiden Ebenen beträgt 3. (= The distance between the two planes is 3)
- Der Abstand / die Distanz zwischen dem Schalter und dem Tresor beträgt 10 Meter. (= The distance between the counter and the safe is 10 meters) ( bank context)

Comment: Meiner Ansicht nacht gibt es die im ersten Satz genannte Unterscheidung nicht. Das eine ist ein deutsches Wort und das andere ein Fremdwort.

Comment: @guidot   You should make this a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Abstand* und *Distanz* sind größtenteils Synonyme, *Distanz* ist ein Fremdwort.

Es gibt einige sehr kleine Unterschiede in der Verwendung von *Abstand* und *Distanz* (gleichzeitig eine Widerlegung der These, dass es bei Leichtathletik immer "Strecke hieße - Das stimmt nicht ganz):

> Müller ist unser bester 1000m-Läufer. Auf diese Distanz hat er noch jeden seiner Konkurrenten geschlagen.

(Hier funktioniert "Abstand" nicht.)

> Müller war bei den 1000m-Läufen wieder mit Abstand der beste Läufer. Er ließ alle Konkurrenten hinter sich.

(Hier funktioniert "Distanz" nicht. "mit Abstand" ist eine stehende Wendung)

Sowohl *Abstand* als auch *Distanz* können im mathematischen/wissenschaftlichen Kontext verwendet werden. Es mag sein, dass es hier eine leichte Präferenz für das Fremdwort gibt.

Comment: Ich denke, dass „Distanz“ eher mit „Entfernung“ austauschbar ist.

Comment: @CarstenS Auch nicht ganz - "Entfernung" funktioniert nicht mit der Laufstrecke

Comment: Das wäre ja auch zu einfach;) Andererseits hast Du kein Beispiel genannt, bei dem „Abstand“ und „Distanz“ gleich gut passen. Ich würde zum Beispiel in der Mathematik immer vom Abstand zweier Punkte reden.

Comment: Für Abstände, die trennen, wird Distanz allerdings auch verwendet. Schwierig.

Comment: Die *Distanz zweier Punkte* geht aber auch ohne weiteres

Comment: Ich finde zumindest Beispiele dafür. Wahrscheinlich sich die beiden auseinander gelebt.

Answer (score 1):

As we see from the other answers here: there is no clear semantical differentiation of

> Distanz, Abstand, Entfernung, Strecke

The difference is a pragmatic one: these words tend to be used in different use-cases. They are actually interchangeable to large extent; but in practice the individual words seem to be used in certain situations with preference. You could perfectly well say:

> Fritz ist den 100-Meter-Abstand in 11 Sekunden gelaufen.

But in practice you do not do this. The most popular solutions are:

> Fritz ist die 100-Meter-Distanz in 11 Sekunden gelaufen.
>
> Fritz ist die 100-Meter-Strecke in 11 Sekunden gelaufen.

There is, admittedly, a slight semantical difference between *Distanz* and *Strecke*. *Distanz* focuses on the end points, whereas *Strecke* focuses on the space between. Insofar is *Strecke* her a bit the odd sibling. But there is no semantical difference between *Abstand* and *Distanz*.

Another criterion for selection is style. You may in certain contexts or text fornms prefer *Distanz* as it sounds more scientific, or *Abstand* because it plays on the field of effortless everyday language.

(Ach Verzeihung, die Frage war auf Deutsch gestellt... aber macht nix, oder?)

Answer (score 0):

Mit der absoluten Entfernung hat das nichts zu tun: Planeten haben auch einen Abstand zur Sonne.

Ich würde argumentieren, dass **Strecke** den kompletten Weg dazwischen meint; den werden Planeten oder der vorsichtige Wanderer der zum Abgrund Abstand hält, nie zurücklegen, im Gegensatz zum genannte Läufer. Feste Wendungen wie *auf Distanz gehen* oder *Abstand halten* sind weitgehend auf ein Wort festgelegt (hier kann trotz gleicher Beduetung nicht durch das Synonym ersetzt werden), sonst sehe ich keinen Unterschied.